# Method scope search in intellij - find all exceptions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my java project I have a method, and would like to know how to find all usages of a specific Exception-class in the class call hierarchy.

Is it possible to have a method-scope-search (with call hierarchy)?

E.g since this wasn't that easy to understand.

FirstClass.method() call the following methods in two other classes; 
SecondClass.method()
ThirdClass.method()

In both SecondClass and ThirdClass a "new SpecificException()" might be trown.

I'd like to know all places where this specific exception can been thrown, specifically relating to the FirstClass.method().

Comment: Just right click on that class or method you will get option of `find usage`.

Comment: I'd recommend searching for the exception class.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but only in the just released IntelliJ IDEA 16 EAP. Here's how:

- Invoke *Call Hierarchy* on FirstClass.method()
- Browse the hierarchy tree to show all methods you are interested in
- Invoke *Find Usages* on the exception constructor
- Edit the *Find Usages Settings* to *Include overloaded methods* and search in the Scope *Hierarchy 'Callees of method'*

This will show everywhere in the hierarchy the exception is created (new expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You could use ALT + F7 key on the exception-class ?

Comment: Shortcuts are depend upon key-mapping. Specify the key mapping also.

Comment: No sorry, I need it to be method-hierarchy-call-scope.